# Remove Home Page URL from an App Registration using Graph Rest API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration

I'm trying to remove a Home Page URL from an Azure App Registration using Graph Rest API following MS Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Graph Does not throw any exceptions when I am passing null. Returning 204. However, Home Page URL is not removed.

If I am passing empty string, Graph throwing exceptions which is valid .

```
var updateApp = new Application
                {
                    Web = new WebApplication
                    {
                        HomePageUrl = null
                    },
                    
                };
 await graphClient.Applications[applicationObjectId].Request().UpdateAsync(updateApp);
```

Can someone help me how to remove existing Home Page URL using Graph in C#?

Comment: Have you tried to set the HomepPageUrl to an empty string ("")?

Comment: yes. Graph throwing error.

Comment: Hi @learner, I tried the same way by giving `HomePageUrl = null` and it worked for me. Note that, there will be slight delay to reflect in Portal. When I refreshed after few minutes, home page URL removed successfully. Could you please check the same and confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, there will be a **slight delay** in Portal to reflect the changes after running the code.

I registered one Azure AD application and added sample **Home Page URL** as below:

[image]

To **remove** this existing Home Page URL using Graph in C#, I ran below code:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var updateApp = new Application
{
    Web = new WebApplication
    {
        HomePageUrl = null,
    },
};

try
{
    var result = await graphClient.Applications["appObjectId"].PatchAsync(updateApp);
    Console.WriteLine("Home Page URL removed successfully");
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal after **few minutes** by refreshing the page, Home Page URL **removed** successfully in the application as below:

[image]

Comment: PatchAsync  working as expected.